# Checked value disappear after post back

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, webforms, bootstrap-4

I am using below tutorial to create image check box

[enter link description here](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/image-checkbox-buttons)

it works properly but once page post back it lose the checked element and cannot retrieve it .

is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: you need to have some sort of session storage on post end and in actual view check if you have that value in session.. that should do the trick

Comment: It is unlikely people will click on your link to see the tutorial. Your best bet is to provide a [mcve] in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolute normal if you not save the post back somewhere and then render again the controls with the one that is selected with that class `active`, the rest controls with out that class...

See the javascript code from your page:

```
$(function () {
    $('.btn-radio').click(function(e) {
        $('.btn-radio').not(this).removeClass('active')
            .siblings('input').prop('checked',false)
            .siblings('.img-radio').css('opacity','0.5');
        $(this).addClass('active')
            .siblings('input').prop('checked',true)
            .siblings('.img-radio').css('opacity','1');
    });
});
```

The selected have the `active` class !, so after the post back, save the user selection and render the selected control with that class.